# чем заменить break в с#?

Tags: break

подскажите пожалуйста ,чем заменить break? В колледже что-то говорили про флаг, но не знаю как его реализовать в программе

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Введите а");
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите b");
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int p = a++; p <= b; p++)
{
  for (int i = 2; i <= p; i++)
  {
    if (p % i == 0 && i != p )
    {
      break;
    }
    else if (p%i==0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Простые числа : " + p);
      break;
    }
  }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так флагом и замените

```cs
for (int p = a++; p <= b; p++)
{
  bool process = true;
  for (int i = 2; i <= p && process; i++)
  {
    if (p % i == 0)
    {
      if (i == p)
        Console.WriteLine("Простые числа : " + p);
      process = false;
    }
  }
}
```